# Nature of the Continuum

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

When we construct the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ we state that every element $x$ is a limit of some rational Cauchy sequence $\{x_i\}$. Two Cauchy sequences $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are equal if they are eventually $\epsilon$-close together, when $i,j\in  \mathbb{N}$ are big enough, for every small rational number $\epsilon$.

Does this mean that every rational point $x$ in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is actually an "extended point" $B_\delta (x)$, where $\delta$ is some *ultra* small rational number? If this is the case then due to overlapping of those open balls it's easy to understand why $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected and why continuity exist.

Comment: What do you mean, "extended point"? What do you mean, "*ultra* small rational number"?

Comment: @60005.  "extended point" could mean that everything within that open ball is all the same, so that on a very small scale numbers become blurred. I don't have definite answer :)

Comment: @Juho a ball of radius $\delta$ around a point necessarily contains real (and even rational!) numbers which are not equal to your original point. So there is no sense in which everything in a small open ball is the same. I don't think you can get much useful intuition by thinking this way.

Comment: The language of the question does remind me of A. Robinson's construction of non-standard reals, (to my perception) by modifying the equivalence relation one "mods out by" to make the ordinary reals (... non-principal ultrafilter...) "Taking standard part" (especially in E. Nelson's IST version) seems consonant with the tone of this question, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this addresses your question - I don't know what you mean by "extended point," "ultra small," or your last sentence - but this might be helpful:

There is a sense in which each real number is "thick" - a real number is not a Cauchy sequence, but rather an *equivalence class* of Cauchy sequences. We can think of *individual* Cauchy sequences as being "ultra close" to each other - for instance, $(0, 0, 0, 0,  . . .)$ and $(1, 0.1, 0.001, 0.0001, . . .)$ are "ultra close" - but the real numbers are formed by "smooshing together" all the ultra-close Cauchy sequences. That is, we have an equivalence relation on Cauchy sequences (two Cauchy sequences are equivalent if the differences of their terms go to zero), and a real number is just an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences.

Now this does mean something slightly surprising: a rational number is not the same as a rational number! Okay, what on earth do I mean by that? Well, the rational number ${1\over 2}$ (e.g.) is **not** a priori the same thing as the equivalence class of Cauchy sequences which includes $({1\over 2}, {1\over 2}, {1\over 2}, . . . )$ - the latter is a set of sequences of rational numbers, and the former is just one single rational number. We (after the fact) identify the two. So there is something a bit surprising going on, but it's really a **type** issue, not something about open balls.

Comment: Thanks! Off topic question: what is the cardinality of equivalence class of Cauchy sequences for one real number? Can it be uncountable?

Comment: Not off topic at all, I think this is closely related. Every equivalence class has the same cardinality as every other equivalence class, and this cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$: the same size as the set of *all* Cauchy sequences, and the *number* of distinct Cauchy sequences. In particular, the equivalence classes corresponding to rationals are exactly as large as the other equivalence classes.

Comment: So we need the concept of uncountable set before we can construct Real numbers?

Comment: Basically, yes - building the real numbers requires us to talk about sets of rationals, and this puts us squarely in the realm of (low-level) set theory. In particular, from very *very* basic axioms about how sets of rational number should behave, you can prove that there are uncountably many of them. The extent to which we need set theory to study the real numbers is a super interesting question, and is basically the subject of **Reverse Mathematics**.

Comment: But if the construction of Real numbers requires use of uncountable sets, isn't it then circular reasoning to "prove" that the set of Real numbers is uncountable?

Comment: @Juho We use uncountable sets to construct the real numbers, then prove that the thing we constructed is uncountable. However, we don't use real numbers to DEFINE uncountable sets, so there's no circular reasoning going on.

Answer (score 1):

No, every rational point in $\mathbb{R}$ is just a point. Take a Cauchy sequence $\{a_i\}$ which represents $x$, and a Cauchy sequence $\{b_i\}$ which represents some point you think is in the "extended point" $B_\delta(x)$, but which is NOT equivalent to the Cauchy sequence $\{a_i\}$. Since the two Cauchy sequences are not equivalent, that means that for a certain $\delta$ and a certain $N$, for all $i,j>N$, $|a_i-b_j|>\delta$. Thus, there is no sense in which $x$ contains Cauchy sequences that are "ultra" close to it, but not equal to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That $\delta$ could be just a symbol for very small positive rational number that can be attached into the structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$. My aim here is to have a practical picture of continuum.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by replacing every number by a ball around that number, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to imagine how it is possible to move continuously from one point to another. Using a collection of little balls that overlapps it's easy to imagine path from A to B. Of course this is not any theory.

Comment: Yeah, that's a tricky thing to imagine. One thing that might help more is the idea of topological connectedness/disconnectedness, which is a bit more well-defined then what you're talking about. Intuitively, though, you know that the real numbers are *complete*, which means there aren't any "holes".